# passing react navigation goBack as reference

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

So When I try to pass in goBack function as a reference it doesn't work for some reason, I need to encapsulate it as an anonymous function for it to work. Is there a reason why this is the case?

I want this to work! (Below)

```
<Button onPress={this.props.navigation.goBack} />
```

But only this works (Below)

```
<Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()} />
```

Is `this` loosing its reference? Thanks!

EDIT: I noticed that the document also uses anonymous function to invoke `goBack`. Curious why this is the case.

Comment: The fat arrow is preserving the `this` context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `<Button onPress={this.props.navigation.goBack} />` does not work is that `goBack` expect a `null` or `undefined` as the first parameter to have the default behavior of going back just one screen.

When you use the handler like this `onPress={this.props.navigation.goBack}`, the handler will invoke `goBack` with the event that is passed back by the handler, i.e. `this.props.navigation.goBack(event)`.

`event` is not null so the `goBack` function will try to pass that as a key to the screen to `goBack` from. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop#goBack-Close-the-active-screen-and-move-back. Then, `event` does not match to any of your pre-defined key, so the routing has no effect.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!

Comment: it is unfortunate that they didn't mention in the doc that `goBack` is expecting `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is your issue most likely.

try: `<Button onPress={this.props.navigation.goBack.bind(this)} />`

Refer to this point in the docs for overall methodology / cleaner code:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: I think that `goBack` is itself an arrow function, and therefore cannot be rebound to a new `this`.

Comment: yeah i think so too ^. you can create a variable that's referencing an anonymous function and can pass that function as `this.foo` and it gets invoked properly.